# Youtube Iframe API reports "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'endSeconds' of null" every time when loading specific videos

Tags: javascript, html, runtime-error, youtube-iframe-api

**Issue Description**

Using the Youtube Iframe API to load videos into page dynamically depending on user actions, most of the time it works very well. But certain videos always produce this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'endSeconds' of null
    at Wh (www-embed-player.js:575)
    at ji.n.na (www-embed-player.js:611)
    at ji.n.Oa (www-embed-player.js:600)
    at m (www-embed-player.js:596)
```

**Steps to reproduce**

- Go to https://www.rockthebells.com/pages/the-tube
- Open your console
- Click any video in the grid below to load it and start it
- Notice that most work well!
- Change sorting to "Title A-Z", go to the second page, and click "BIG PIMPIN' - JAY-Z FT. UGK"
- Note that the above error shows in the console and the video fails to load
- Head over to Youtube, view any video, then replace the video id in the url with the video id of the clicked item from the previous site. Note that it works just fine.

**Relevant code**

In the page `HEAD`

```
<script defer="defer" src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
```

In `application.js`

```
window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {
  console.log('onYouTubeIframeAPIReady');

  $(function() {
    $("[data-video-select-container]").each(function() {
      const container = $(this);
      const iframeTarget = container.find('[data-video-select-target]');
      const iframeTargetId = iframeTarget.attr('id');
      const defaultVideoId = iframeTarget.data('default-video-id');
      const titleEl = container.find('[data-video-select-title]');
      const artistEl = container.find('[data-video-select-artist]');
      const buttons = container.find('[data-video-select-video]');
      let player;

      console.log('data-video-select-container', {
        container, iframeTarget, iframeTargetId, titleEl, artistEl, buttons
      });

      function onPlayerReady() {
        console.log('onPlayerReady');

        buttons.click(function(){
          const btn = $(this);
          const video = btn.data('video-select-video');
          console.log('video btn click', { video });

          player.loadVideoById(video.id);
          artistEl.text(video.artist);
          titleEl.text(video.title);
        });
      }

      function onPlayerStateChange() {}

      function startPlayer(videoId) {
        player = new YT.Player(iframeTargetId, {
          height: '100%',
          width: '100%',
          videoId: videoId,
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
      }

      if (defaultVideoId) {
        startPlayer(defaultVideoId);
      } else {
        const firstBtn = buttons.first();
        const firstVideo = firstBtn.data('video-select-video');
        artistEl.text(firstVideo.description);
        titleEl.text(firstVideo.title);
        startPlayer(firstVideo.id);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

**Other Notes**

I've done quite a bit of searching around and I'm unable to find a similar posted question, but I apologize if I missed it.

My guess is that the videos I'm trying to load are specifically disabled from being loaded via the IFrame API by Youtube or the video author. But the error doesn't indicate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed the same error on some other of the player methods that use an argument syntax for the parameters. The solution is to use the object parameter's method alternatives.

```
youtubePlayer.loadById({
  videoId: videoId,
  startSeconds: 0,
  endSeconds: 180
});
```

Both startSeconds and endSeconds field are optional.

Comment: Don't have the code in front of me to test anymore, but looks like a valid fix. Will mark as accepted - thank you!